# Userinfo command

Tags: python, discord.py

I made such a command but I dont  want that bot says everyone by roles part and I want to see the permission keys can someone help me?

```
@client.command()
async def userinfo(ctx, target: Optional[Member]):
    if ctx.author.guild_permissions.administrator:
        x = ctx.guild.members
        if target in x:
             roles = [role for role in target.roles]
             embed = discord.Embed(title="User information", colour=discord.Color.gold(), timestamp=datetime.utcnow())

             embed.set_author(name=target.name, icon_url=target.avatar_url)

             embed.set_thumbnail(url=target.avatar_url)

             embed.set_footer(text="Mr.KapiBara", icon_url="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/618434755981213716/718861010223497236/kapi-1.png")

             fields = [("Name", str(target), False),
                   ("ID", target.id, False),
                   ("Status", str(target.status).title(), False),
                   (f"Roles ({len(roles)})", " ".join([role.mention for role in roles]), False),
                   ("Created at", target.created_at.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S"), False),
                   ("Joined at", target.joined_at.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S"), False)]

             for name, value, inline in fields:
                    embed.add_field(name=name, value=value, inline=inline)

             await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        else:
            await ctx.send(f'You have to ping soneone from this server')
    else:
        await ctx.send(f'Not enough permissions')
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
roles = [role for role in target.roles]
```

That comprehension is getting every role.

You can use a condition to allow all roles except `@everyone`, which is known as the default role:

```py
roles = [role for role in target.roles if role != ctx.guild.default_role]
```

---

**References:**

- [`Guild.default_role`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.default_role)
- [`Guild.roles`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.roles)